# Using bindingsource stored in the ifs

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg, ibm-ifs

Is there any possible way to create a serviceprogramm (crtsqlrpgi OBJTYPE(*SRVPGM)) using a .bnd file stored in the ifs as bindingsource?

Comment: Is this because the control spec H BNDDIR('xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx') does not take an IFS path, but only a library path?  And because CRTSQLRPGI does not have a BNDDIR parameter like CRTBNDRPG?

Comment: I don't wanna store the bnddir in the ifs. I wanna store the .bnd file (YOURLIB/QSRVSRC/X.bnd) and reference it with a parm like stmfBndSrc(ifsPath).

Comment: Can't try it myself here but maybe `exec sql COMPILEOPT = 'SRCSTMF(''/path-to-file.bnd'')'` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, [Create Service Program (CRTSRVPGM)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/crtsrvpgm.htm) has a SRCSTMF (Export source stream file) parameter.

Appears to have been added at v7.3.

Comment: yeah but not for the bindingsource normally populated in the qsrvsrc sourcefile :(. I guess ill create some bndpgms and cluster them as srvpgm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it. I created my program with crtsqlrpgi ... objtype(*module) and then created the srvpgm.

Comment: How does that solve the problem of using the IFS to store binder source?